# Is there a way of flagging "tags" as off-topic, warning the asker when they select them?

Tags: discussion

Things like "mvc", "web-development", etc are clear red flags that the question has a decent chance of being off-topic.  Would be awesome if there was a way of setting these up as "warning" tags.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has been discussed over on meta.stackoverflow.com and the basic answer is no. There are tag synonyms (https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/tags/synonyms/) but that's it.

[You can see it here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18795/automatic-wrong-site-suggestion-when-posting). (turns out it's actually a question I asked, but I don't remember asking it...)

Comment: Bummer.  I understand the reluctance to complicate the system, but...